# Different AuthenticationManager per path/route in spring security in MvC

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

### Preamble

Since there are a lot of questions on StackOverflow about this already, I first want to ensure that this is not a duplicate and differentiate.

This is about

- Having 2(or more) different AuthenticationProviders in 2 different AuthenticationManagers to be used on different routes.
- Using the methods in Spring Security 5.5 not 3.x
- Using a non XML configuration based approach

So the question is not about:

- How to include several AuthenticationProvideres in on AuthenticationManager to offer "alternative authentications" (which most questions tend to be)

### Case

Assume one has 2 custom AuthenticationProviders: **CATApiTokenProvider** and **DOGApiTokenProvider**. It is by design that we not talk about AOuth/JWT/Basic/Form providers, since they offer shortcuts.

Now we have 2 REST API endpoints `/dog/endpoint` and `/cat/endpoint`.

### Question

How would one properly implement this today, with Spring Security 5.5:

- We want the authentication provider `CATApiTokenProvider` to **only** be able to authenticate requests on `/cat/endpoint`
- We want the authentication provider `DOGApiTokenProvider` to **only** be able to authenticate requests on `/dog/endpoint`

So one cannot authenticate with a cat token on `/dog/endpoint` and neither with a dog token on `/cat/endpoint`.

**My Ideas/Approaches**

a) I understand that since I have custom Cat/Dog filters, one can use the `AuthenticationManagerResolver` and pass one instance into the filter when creating the bean. This resolver might look like

```java
  public AuthenticationManagerResolver<HttpServletRequest> resolver()
  {
    return request -> {
      if (request.getPathInfo().startsWith("/dog/")) {
        try {
          return ???;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
          log.error(exception);
        }
      }
      if (request.getPathInfo().startsWith("/cat/")) {
        try {
          return ???;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
          log.error(exception);
        }
      }
    };
  }
```

Two questions with that would be:

- how to return different authentication managers here? How to instantiate 2 different AM with each one CatAP and DogAP? Currently I use  `public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` but as far as I understand, I would only configure 'the one' AuthenticationManager and I could add DogAP and CatAP there, but this would let as having 1 AM with 2 APs, so when using this AM i could auth with the dog token on the cat endpoint
- is this really the right way to implement this? I would have expected to be able to provide the AM on the SecurityConfiguration level

b) Somehow instantiate 2 different AuthenticationManagers and then use the SecurityConfiguration to assign them to different matchers.

Two questions:

- what is the right way to spawn 2 different AMs with different providers?
- I cannot understand how I would add an AM for a spec

```java
http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/dog/**")
      .?
```

Answer (score 5):

You can either publish multiple filter chains or wire your own `AuthenticationFilter` with an `AuthenticationManagerResolver`

You may use `AuthenticationManagerResolver` to return different `AuthenticationManager`s. Since Spring Security 5.4.0, we don't need to extend the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to configure our `SecurityFilterChain` anymore, you can instead define a bean of `SecurityFilterChain` type.

I'll go into detail on wiring your own `AuthenticationFilter`.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain apiSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.addFilterBefore(apiAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    private AuthenticationFilter apiAuthenticationFilter() {
        AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new AuthenticationFilter(new ApiAuthenticationManagerResolver(), new BasicAuthenticationConverter());
        authenticationFilter.setSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {});
        return authenticationFilter;
    }

    public static class ApiAuthenticationManagerResolver implements AuthenticationManagerResolver<HttpServletRequest> {

        private final Map<RequestMatcher, AuthenticationManager> managers = Map.of(
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/dog/**"), new DogAuthenticationProvider()::authenticate,
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/cat/**"), new CatAuthenticationProvider()::authenticate
        );

        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager resolve(HttpServletRequest request) {
            for (Map.Entry<RequestMatcher, AuthenticationManager> entry : managers.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getKey().matches(request)) {
                    return entry.getValue();
                }
            }
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to resolve AuthenticationManager");
        }
    }

    public static class DogAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            if (authentication.getName().endsWith("_dog")) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials(),
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_DOG"));
            }
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Username should end with _dog");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
            return true;
        }

    }

    public static class CatAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            if (authentication.getName().endsWith("_cat")) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials(),
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_CAT"));
            }
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Username should end with _cat");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

In the example above, we have two `AuthenticationProvider`s, one for cat and other for dog. They are resolved upon an `AntPathRequestMatcher` matching for both `/dog/**` and `/cat/**` endpoints, inside the `ApiAuthenticationManagerResolver`. There is no need to defined an `AuthenticationManager` for each dog and cat, since `AuthenticationProvider/Manager` have the same interface.

The `ApiAuthenticationManagerResolver` is then wired inside an `AuthenticationFilter` in your filter chain.

You can also define two different filter chains for each endpoint, like so:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain dogApiSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatchers((matchers) -> matchers
                .antMatchers("/dog/**"));
    http.authorizeRequests((authz) -> authz
            .anyRequest().authenticated());
    http.httpBasic();
    http.authenticationProvider(new DogAuthenticationProvider());
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain catApiSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatchers((matchers) -> matchers
                .antMatchers("/cat/**"));
    http.authorizeRequests((authz) -> authz
            .anyRequest().authenticated());
    http.httpBasic();
    http.authenticationProvider(new CatAuthenticationProvider());
    return http.build();
}
```

Please, when defining multiple filter chains, the ordering is important, make use of the `@Order` annotation in those scenarios.

When you do `http.requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/endpoint/**"));` you are telling Spring Security to only call the filter chain when the request matches that path.

There is also a [ticket within Spring Security's repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6762) to provide a `AuthenticationManagerResolver` implementation which accepts `Map<RequestMatcher, AuthenticationManager>`, it would be nice if you think it makes sense, give a thumbs up there.